# Have to reinstall NVidia driver on every reboot

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, x11, nvidia

I am having an issue with my Nvidia driver after the latest update. Now, Every time I reboot the machine there is some conflict between two different version and I have to reinstall the driver before X starts. Here is the message from the log file:

```
Jun 11 20:28:20 localhost kernel: [   73.033810] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 270.41.19, but
Jun 11 20:28:20 localhost kernel: [   73.033811] NVRM: this kernel module has the version 270.29.  Please
Jun 11 20:28:20 localhost kernel: [   73.033812] NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
Jun 11 20:28:20 localhost kernel: [   73.033813] NVRM: components have the same version.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Nvidia driver has two parts, the kernel part and a userspace part. They have to match. Usually when you install the Nividia driver it builds the kernel part as a module. You may not have two versions of the Nvidia driver installed, but there is the old module, or you are booting an older kernel from grub. See if there is a newer kernel you can select from grub that may have to newer kernel part.

Answer (score 1):

One way for such a mismatch between kernel module(s) and userland driver parts to occur is when your distribution boots up with a ramdisk. If this is the case, you need to re-run `grub-install` (or the likes) so that the new kernel module is loaded on system boot.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Keith, above - you likely have installed two different nvidia drivers over time. My suggested remedy would be:

1. ensure you've updated to the most recent kernel for your distribution
2. ensure you have installed kernel headers and any other dependent packages required for nvidia kernel module compilation
3. reboot (to your latest kernel)
4. install the 'dkms' package, if available for your distribution
5. download the latest stable nvidia driver, do a 'full' install with it (installing the userspace drivers and kernel modules), and enable support for dkms when answering the installer questions
6. ensure the install reports 'success' and then reboot

This process will get you on the latest kernel, the latest nvidia driver, and will enable the dkms auto-rebuild capability to allow the system to automatically build and deploy appropriate nvidia kernel modules with future kernel upgrades.